# Multiple simultaneous user access with same credentials

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET website where multiple users access the site using same user credentials. The site functions fine when used by single user, however when a second user with the same credentials logs in simultaneously and the first user performs any action (clicks any link, selects any dropdown etc.), the first user is redirected to the default/login page. I want both the users to access the site without any trouble.

Can any one comment on why this is happening and how this can be solved.

Comment: Why would you have multiple users with the same credentials?

Comment: Any password shared by two people is not a password.

Comment: There are two level of users, the first level of users approve the changes in site and the second level of users are the end users who use the site. The first level users have the same credentials while the second level users have unique credentials.

Comment: A shared set of credentials of users who make prod changes seems like a terrible idea..

Comment: I think OP is asking a completely different question, you guys... You never know what the requirements are...

Comment: The requirement can be considered as creating a demo website, where multiple users can access the site using the same credentials.

Answer (score 1):

My guess for the reason of the behaviour would be the authentication method you are using. Probably when the first user logs in he gets a session ID that authorises him for the following requests.

When another user uses the same credentials to log in, different session ID is created for that user so the ID the first user has is not valid any more, and therefore he gets redirected to the login page.

Comment: Does there exists an one-to-one mapping on web server between the session id and credentials, i.e credentials are mapped to only one session id?

Comment: What form of authentication are you using?